# Bash json request to api

Tags: json, bash, curl

I am trying to post Json data to an api. All i am getting back is an "Invalid Command" error. I have contacted the api developer about the issue and they insist that the error is not in their api.

Here is the request i am trying to send.

```
$(curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '"{\"key\":\"MYKEY\", \"secret\":\"MYSECRET\", \"data\":{\"instance\":\"UHC\"}}"'  https://api.creeper.host/minecraft/startserver)
```

Here is what i get back

```
{"status":"error","message":"Invalid: command not found"}
```

Does this look correct to everyone?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to quote the string (you have an extra set of quotes as well), pass it via standard input.

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" \
     -X POST -d@- https://api.creeper.host/minecraft/startserver <<EOF
{"key": "MYKEY", "secret": "MYSECRET", "data": {"instance": "UHC"}}
EOF
```